# Covariance problem with mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have problem that can't solve correctly.

Let $X_1 , X_2 ,\cdots, X_n$ be independent and identicaly distributed with \mu being mean. I have to show that 
$$\operatorname*{Cov}(\mu , X_r - \mu) = 0 ,~1\leq r\leq n$$
I have tried to put this covariance in terms of expected values by its definition, but it just doesn't work out. Is this wrong way to approach this or am I doing some algebraic mistakes?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The mean $\mu$ is deterministic, so I'm not sure this proof would have much value. The covariance of anything with a deterministic quantity should be zero, right? 
$$\text{cov}(a, Y) = E[aY^T] - E[a]E[Y]^T = aE[Y]^T - aE[Y]^T = 0$$
Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting thing would be to show that $\text{cov}(Y, Z-Y) = 0$ for any random variables $Y$ and $Z$, which is cool because it further makes clear how random variables form a Hilbert space. Is that what you mean to show?

Answer (score 1):

We have that the covariance of two random variables $X,Y$ is the expectation of $(X-\mathbf{E}[X])(Y-\mathbf{E}[Y])$, so when one of $X$ and $Y$ is a constant random variable, as in your case, this is just zero :)